# On Perelman's paper

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, ricci-flow

In section 5 in "**[The entropy formula for the Ricci flow and its geometric applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211159)**" *Perelman* has written:

Fix a closed manifold $M$ with a probability measure $m$, and suppose
that our system is described by a metric $g_{ij}(\tau)$, which depends on the **temperature**
$\tau$ according to equation $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}g_{ij}=2(R_{ij}+\nabla_i \nabla_j f)$ where $dm = udV$, $u =(4\pi \tau)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-f} $, and the partition function is given by $\log Z = \int (−f + \frac{n}{2})dm$.

**Question 1:** We know $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g_{ij}=-2(R_{ij}+\nabla_i \nabla_j f)$ is modified Ricci flow, where $t$ is time. Why the changes of the metric respect to $\tau$  is exactly backward of the changes of the metric respect to $t$?

**Question 2:**  $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}g_{ij}=2(R_{ij}+\nabla_i \nabla_j f)$ is backward to heat equation PDE, Is there a solution to this?

**Question 3:** Why is the partition function $\log Z =\int (−f + \frac{n}{2})dm$?

Comment: you're asking for an explanation of Perelman's intuition to relate the Ricci flow to thermodynamics; many asked that question, an insightful analysis has been given here: 

http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5193

Comment: @Carlo: That's a good reference but it obfuscates an important part of the story: the relation to QFT and the renormalization group stated explicitly by Perelman on Page 3 of his article cited by the OP. Perhaps the review by Li should be complemented with https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00032-010-0110-y